# What do I do with the potentiometer on Adafruit RGB LCD

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

So I just got my [Adafruit RGB backlight positive LCD 16x2 + extras - black on RGB](https://www.adafruit.com/product/398) In [this picture](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/970x728/398-11.jpg) it shows a potentiometer beside the LCD. Anyone know where this is supposed to go?

[image]

If it helps, I'm mounting the shields on an [Adafruit I2C Controlled + Keypad Shield Kit for 16x2 LCD](https://www.adafruit.com/product/715)

Comment: It goes the same place as for any other LCD. Just because the backlight is an RGB LED doesn't change how the LCD functions.

Comment: It's the same pot (functionally) as the orange one in the shield kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potentiometer is for setting the contrast level of the LCD. The Shield Kit shown also comes with a pot (the one with the orange face). Assembled it should look like this:

[image: Assembled LCD Shield Kit]

Notice the pot in the lower right corner to the right of the microcontroller ic and above the reset button.

Answer (score 1):

The contrast is set by inputting an analog voltage into Pin 3 on the LCD header. The analog voltage is created using the potentiometer and is easily adjusted by the user when in operation.

The diagram below shows (only) the circuit needed to adjust the contrast on the LCD display.

[image: LCD Contrast wiring]